# Looking to influence/read OpenGL/DirectX of another application

Tags: opengl, directx

I am looking to influence another OpenGL or DirectX application, similar to Nvidia Vision or Tridef.

I am looking to change the camera position slightly and capture the resulting framebuffer, similar to Tridef and Nvidia. I am not interested in updating the framebuffer, this would be for the purpose of stereoscopic screenshots (outputting to files), hence if necessary it can be somewhat performance requiring (there is no need for fluent video).

As I take it, OpenGL and DirectX require different practices for this. Preferably I'd like to aim at DirectX.

Another option for me would be to capture the depth buffer and framebuffer, and use reprojection to create the stereoscopic capture.

To sum it up:

- What is the name of the technique where one influences another
  applications OpenGL / DirectX calls?
- Would OpenGL or DirectX be
  easier than the other?
- Would it be easier to read the frame and
  depthmap?
- Do you have any pointers/documentation you know of for the
  above? (This is the main question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is called hooking.  The idea is that you trick another program into calling your functions instead of library functions so that you can change the behavior.  It's generally done either through either some API provided by your OS, or by fooling the linker into linking against a dll you made which has the same name as the dll the application is actually trying to use.

I'm not very familiar with hookinh, but the wikipedia article has some examples including one that uses direct3d: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooking

Comment: DLLs are the purview of the loader, not the linker.  And yes, DLL injection is useful in this scenario.  But no, creating a name collision is not the usual way to do it.